# Python RabbitMQ client hanging

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a simple python script based on the RabbitMQ *send.py* example. The original *send.py* works fine on my setup, but when I use an added user and virtual host, the script hangs when performing `connection.channel()`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pika
import json

def getMessageFromFile():
    json_data=open('d:\src\TestData.json')
    data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()
    return data

print "getting msg"
msg = getMessageFromFile()
print "creating credentials"
credentials = pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('DevUser', 'DevPassword')
print "getting connection"
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', virtual_host='TestVirtualHost', credentials=credentials, socket_timeout=1000, port=5672))
print "getting channel"
channel = connection.channel()
print "getting queue"
channel.queue_declare(queue='TestWorkQueue')

data_string = json.dumps(msg)
print "sending msg"
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='TestWorkQueue', body=data_string)
print "msg sent"

connection.close()

print "done"
```

When I run it I see this:

```
getting msg
creating credentials
getting connection
getting channel
```

at which point the script hangs for about 10 minutes. Then it prints:

```
getting queue
```

and then crashing with a `pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed` exception.

My guess is that the channel is not really there, but there is no indication that `connection.channel()` failed.

Comment: What version of pika/rabbitmq do you use? Have you added the user 'DevUser' and vhost 'TestVirtualHost' at RabbitMQ server?

Comment: I'm using the 3.2.3 version of rabbit. Yes, I used the rabbitmqctl.bat script to add the user/password and the virtual host. Last night I wrote a C++ client that uses the above details and works fine, but I need this to work in Python. Very puzzling.

Comment: Can you include the full exception traceback? Also, what version of pika do you use?

Comment: What does the RabbitMQ logs say?